# Django-Reversion: Accessing QuerySet Data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-reversion

I have a model that is under version control using Django-Reversion. Within a Terminal window I can access all of the previous versions of a model instance using:

```
foo = FooModel.objects.get()
versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(foo)
```

When I check `versions` it's a set of all the previous versions. However when I call this same function in a view and try to add it to context all I get a in a single `VersionQuerySet` that I can't figure out how to iterate through and pull data out of.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try calling `list` on the `versions` object. This should force the QuerySet to evaluate its items:

```
versions = Version.objects.get_for_object(foo)
new_versions = list(versions)
```